# TryCatch with parLapply (Parallel package) in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to run something on a very large dataset.  Basically, I want to loop through all files in a folder and run the function *fromJSON* on it. However, I want it to skip over files that produce an error.  I have built a function using *tryCatch* however, that only works when i use the function *lappy* and not *parLapply*.

Here is my code for my exception handling function:

```
readJson <- function (file) {
 require(jsonlite)
 dat <- tryCatch(
        {
         fromJSON(file, flatten=TRUE)      
        },
         error = function(cond) {
                 message(cond)
                 return(NA)
        },
         warning = function(cond) {
                  message(cond)
                  return(NULL)
                  }
   )
  return(dat)   
}
```

and then I call parLapply on a character vector *files* which contains the full paths to the JSON files:

```
 dat<- parLapply(cl,files,readJson)
```

that produces an error when it reaches a file that doesn't end properly and does not create the list 'dat' by skipping over the problematic file.  Which is what the readJson function was supposed to mitigate.

When I use regular lapply, however it works perfectly fine.  It generates the errors, however, it still creates the list by skipping over the erroneous file.

any ideas on how I could use exception handling with parLappy parallel such that it will skip over the problematic files and generate the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `error` handler function `cond` is an error condition. `message(cond)` signals this condition, which is caught on the workers and transmitted as an error to the master. Either remove the `message` calls or replace them with something like

`message(conditionMessage(cond))`

You won't see anything on the master though, so removing is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this (with another example, reproducible):

```
test1 <- function(i) {
  dat <- NA
  try({
    if (runif(1) < 0.8) {
      dat <- rnorm(i)
    } else {
      stop("Error!")
    } 
  })
  return(dat)   
}
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(3)
dat <- parallel::parLapply(cl, 1:100, test1)
```

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075113/trycatch-with-a-complicated-function-and-plyr-in-r) for other solutions. I think using `foreach` with `.errorhandling = "pass"` would be another good solution.